# How do I move the Grand Total to the bottom of the results set using ROLLUP?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:
[image]

This is my query and the results set:

```
SELECT S.STATE AS State,
       S.City AS City , COUNT(City) AS [Stores in City]
FROM tStore S
GROUP BY ROLLUP(STATE, City)
ORDER BY State, COUNT(City)
```

[image]

The grand total row is at the top! How do I make it appear at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the actual field and the `GROUPING` clause in your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY 
    GROUPING(State),
    State,
    GROUPING(City),
    City
```

Answer (score 1):

Using state `State IS NULL` will not correctly sort rows with NULL value.

You should use `ORDER BY GROUPING(State), ...` to force total to last row.

Answer (score 0):

Your "ORDER BY State" is causing the NULL value to rise to the top.  Just change your "ORDER BY" to something like:

```
ORDER BY case when State IS NULL then 2 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grouping sets`:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (STATE, City), (STATE), () )
```